# Unix shell file search for value pair

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm preforming a customer extract of our CIS and there's a piece of data that I need that's stored in a key,value format in another file.

For example:

File 1 (Extract):

```
1, 3000, 4000, PVXZT1000, 123-3455
2, 4000, 2500, BT21304, 123-3455
```

File 2 (key, value):

```
PVXZT1000, 136-8400
BT21304, 136-8400
```

What I need to do is look-up the value `PVXZT1000` in file 2 and find the value associated with it. I then need to replace the `123-3455` value in file 1 with the new value found in file 2, `136-8400`

Is there an easy & efficient way to do this with the unix shell? Or perhaps AWK?

I'm able to use any of the common unix shells.

Comment: if the key cannot be found in file2 what would you do with file1? clear the value '123-3455' or keep the value untouched? but no matter which rule it should follow, you can find an answer from the two awk experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($4 in a){$5=a[$4]}1' file2 file1
1, 3000, 4000, PVXZT1000, 136-8400
2, 4000, 2500, BT21304, 136-8400
```

This will update `file1` with latest value in `file2` by matching the keys across the files.

**Explanation:**

`NR` is an `awk` variable that contains the current line number being read. `FNR` contains the current line in context to the current file *i.e* everytime we read a new file `FNR` resets to 0 but `NR` does not.

```
          # Looking at file2 first
NR==FNR   # This is only true when we look at the first file
{         # The block to execute if the previous condition is TRUE
a[$1]=$2  # Create a look-up array a: field 1 is the key and field 2 the value
next      # Grab the next line (skips executing any further blocks)
}         # End block
          # We are now looking a file1
($4 in a) # Check in field 4 was in file2
$5=a[$4]  # If found update field 5 with value in the array using the key
}         # End the block
1         # Idiom for printing all the lines
```

If you want to learn `awk` read **[Effective AWK Programming](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/)**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would I need to change anything if I wanted to clear the value in file 1 if the key was not found in file 2? Also, if you have time, is there anyway you could send me a PM and break this down for me? I'd like to understand awk more.

Comment: An explanation benefits all so I've added it to my answer. If you want to clear the value you would drop the check `($4 in a)` i.e. what @user000001 answer does, that is why I added a note to make it clear the difference.

Comment: I'm getting 'awk: syntax error near line 1' & 'awk: bailing out near line 1'. I'm using the syntax you both provided. Is there a way to check if I'm using an older version of awk?

Comment: What is the exact command you ran? What system are you on? The `awk` version can be obtained with `awk --version | head -n 1`

Comment: SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-15 sun4v sparc sun4v. The awk --version | head -n 1 command is just hanging for me. I have gawk 3.0.4 available to me as well.

Comment: On Solaris you want to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working great. I have a follow up question though, is it possible to use 2 columns for the key in the look-up array? Something like a[$1,$2]=$3.

Comment: Yes that is perfectly valid.

Comment: Update - I've got everything implemented as needed. For some reason it's not reading the first record of file2 and thus not finding 1 look-up value. I've gotten around this by adding a blank 1st line in file2. Is the NR==FNR causing it to skip the first record in file2?

Comment: Here's my statement in full: /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{FS=",";OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}{$44=a[$5,$6]}1' file2 file1 > outputfile

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$5=a[$4]}1' file2 file1
```

Comment: Note: this assumes that every value in file1 will be updated with a valid value found in file2.

Comment: @sudo_O Yes you are correct. Your answer is probably more robust